# How do you request a passcode entry when linking out from an app

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

My app keeps failing Apple's review process because it's rated for kids, yet links out to websites without parental controls. I was wondering if there is anything I can put in the HTML link that will force the use to put in their passcode (or thumbprint) before jumping to the link?

I have no idea where to start with this. Google has turned up nothing.

When you click a link in the app, instead of taking you straight to safari, it instead asks for a passcode first. This would satisfy the parental controls issue.

Comment: There is nothing you can put in the link itself. You have to intercept the navigation process from the view controller and trigger some sort of parental gate.  You can't rely on TouchID or the device pass code as the child may be enrolled for TouchID and/or know the passcode.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I was worried this would be the case, but as I built this through phonegap, I don't have the raw coding skills to build a parental gate. It's a shame there is no plugin for this.